# How to use a variable value from mapping for taking a decision to send an email or not

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I'm working on a requirement where i have to call a Stored Procedure from Informatica Mapping and store the returned value in a variable and pass that variable value to workflow level and then se it in taking decision for sending email or not.

I have created the mapping but not sure how to pass the variable value into the email task.

Any suggestions on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Mapping Variable` and set it with `SetVariable` function. Next, create a Workflow variable and use it on your session `Components` tab, in `Post-session on success variable assignment` to pass the value from your mapping variable, to your workflow variable. Then use the workflow variable in your email task - or anywhere else in the workflow.

It's a very good idea to initialize your variable with some default value, like -999 for example, using `Assignment task` in the workflow and then also use the `Pre-session variable assignment` to pass the default value to the mapping variable. Otherwise you may be processing with the value persisted in the repository.